# statsmodels PCA eigenvalues sum

Tags: python, pca, statsmodels

When I apply `statsmodels.multivariate.pca.PCA` to some data, I am finding that the sum of the produced eigenvalues does not equal to the total variance of the data. I am using the following code

```py
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

corr_matrix = np.array([
    [1, 0.8, 0.4],
    [0.8, 1, 0.6],
    [0.4, 0.6, 1]])

Z = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0,0], corr, 1000)

pc = sm.PCA(Z, standardize=False, demean=False, normalize=False)

pc.eigenvals.sum()
```

and the result (in a given random sample) is `2994.51488403581` while I was expecting this to add up to `3`.

What am I missing?

**Add 1**

It seems that when the PCA is performed on the data `X` (i.e. using the matrix `X^TX`), the relationship between sum of variances and eigenvalues no longer holds, and it is only when the PCA is performed on the covariance matrix (i.e. on `X^TX/n`) when the sum of eigenvalues is eual to the sum of variances, i.e. `trace(X^TX/n) = sum(eigenvalues)`. I wish this was more clearly stated on all the post one finds on PCA.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues are not the variance of the data. eigenvalues are the variances of the data in specific direction, defined by eigenvectors. The Variance of the data is the sum of the distance of all points to the mean value of the data. PC's are the characteristic of data and shows how the data is expanded in the space in specific directions. You should not confuse the variance of the data with eigenvalue (which shows the variance in the direction of the eigenvector).

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I see everywhere written again and again that `the sum of eigenvalues from PCA equals the total variance`...

Comment: it's not the total variance of the data, it's the sum of variances of every variable/dimension. That's why the sum of PC's is equal to the trace of covariance matrix. the diagonal of covariance matrix has the values of variances of every variable.

Comment: Yes, this is what is called `total variance` as far as I can tell -  the sum of individual variances, i.e. the trace of the co-variance matrix. It seems that there is some normalisation missing (the numebr of observation?) when PCA is applied on the data for this relationship with eigenvalues to hold, but it doesn't seem to be discussed anywhere.

Comment: look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266864/why-is-the-sum-of-eigenvalues-of-a-pca-equal-to-the-original-variance-of-the-dat). I dont think the variance of the data is the sum of all variances of every dimension. that might be true when the data is whitend (all dependencies and cross variances are 0 and the covariance matrix is diagonal) .

Comment: I would suggest to try calculating the trace of cov matrix. if it's not the same as the sum of eigenvalues then you are making a mistake in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, but I do now believe that the issue is with the fact that the PCA on data is proffered with data matrix `X^T X` but the relationship between eigenvalues and total variance holds only when the PCA is performed on the sample covariance matrix `X^T X / n`.

Comment: eigenvalues of X'X are the square of the singular values of X. So, we can compute eigenvalues even if we use SVD(X).

Answer (score 1):

quick answer by reverse engineering (I don't remember the details)

```
pc = PCA(Z, standardize=False, demean=True, normalize=False)
​
pc.eigenvals.sum() / 1000
2.7550787264061087

Z.var(0).sum()
2.7550787264061087
```

In the computation of the variance, the data is demeaned. If we don't demean, then we only get a uncentered quadratic product.

```
pc = PCA(Z, standardize=False, demean=False, normalize=False)
​
pc.eigenvals.sum(), pc.eigenvals.sum() / Z.shape[0]
(2756.1915877060546, 2.7561915877060548)

(Z**2).mean(0).sum()
2.7561915877060548
```